# Is there any cost optimal parallel algorithm for sorting for (EREW PRAM)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

Is there any possibility of obtaining a cost optimal algorithm for sorting n integers with n processors for the [EREW PRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is an algorithm by Richard Cole named "Parallel Merge Sort" which theoretically sorts the input(not just integers) on a EREW PRAM in O(log n) using O(n) processors.

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0217049